# No wifi | Acer Switch 10 | in mode Try ubuntu |

Tags: wireless, keyboard

helo guys,
I am new with Ubuntu, but this is awesome platform :).
I've problem... in my acer switch 10 Wifi not working. 
I try many different ways to solve this but everything thosen't work.
I doing this in "Try Ubuntu(without install)", because I can't download and install a Boot-Repair Disk, because I have Win 8.1 and would like to have Ubuntu. If have find how to manage with Wifi and Keyboard (I this already) After that, I would have only ubuntu on Acer :).

Could you help me :)??

I don't knew if this help you.
Sorry, but I am a new in Ubuntu.
On my second laptop Toshiba A200 - work with ubuntu is much more easier.

Thanks in advance. 
best regards

Lukasz

Please find wireless-info.txt below:

```
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "\n########## wireless info START ##########\n\n"

########## wireless info START ##########

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ REPORTDATE=$(date +"%d %b %Y %H:%M %Z %z")
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ SCRIPTDATE=$(date -u -d "$SCRIPTDATE" +"%d %b %Y %H:%M %Z %z")
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ LASTBOOTDT=$(last -FRn 1 reboot | sed -n 's/.*system boot[ ]\+\ 
(.\+\) - .*$/\1/p')
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ LASTBOOTDT=$(date -d "$LASTBOOTDT" +"%d %b %Y %H:%M %Z %z")
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "Report from: %s\n\n" "$REPORTDATE"
Report from: 28 Jun 2015 05:47 UTC +0000

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "Booted last: %s\n\n" "$LASTBOOTDT"
Booted last: 28 Jun 2015 05:39 UTC +0000

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "Script from: %s\n" "$SCRIPTDATE"
Script from: 21 May 2015 09:10 UTC +0000
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "\n##### release ###########################\n\n"

##### release ###########################

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -idrc
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "\n##### kernel ############################\n\n"

##### kernel ############################

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ uname -srvmpio
Linux 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ echo

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sed 's/root=[^ ]*//;s/[ ]\+/, /g;s/^BOOT_IMAGE=[^ ]*/Parameters 
:/' /proc/cmdline
Parameters: file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed, boot=casper, quiet, splash, --
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "\n##### desktop ###########################\n\n"

##### desktop ###########################

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ if [ -n "$DESKTOP_SESSION" ]; then
> 
>     DESKTOP="$DESKTOP_SESSION"
> 
> else
> 
>     DESKTOP=$(sed -n 's/^Session=\(.\+\)$/\1/p' "$HOME/.dmrc")
> 
>     DESKDMRC=" (from ~/.dmrc)"
> 
> fi
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ if [ -n "$DESKTOP" ]; then
> 
>     if [ -f "/usr/share/xsessions/$DESKTOP.desktop" ]; then
> 
> DESKTOP=$(sed -n 's/^Name=\(.\+\)$/\1/p' "/usr/share/xsessions/$DESKTOP.deskto 
p")
> 
>     fi
> 
>     echo "${DESKTOP/ Session/}${DESKDMRC}"
> 
> else
> 
>     printf "\nCould not be determined.\n"
> 
> fi
Ubuntu
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "\n##### lspci #############################\n\n"

##### lspci #############################

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA 2 '^[^[:space:]].*net' | sed '/^--$/d;/^[ 
^[:space:]]/ i\\'
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "\n##### lsusb #############################\n\n"

##### lsusb #############################

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0930:6544 Toshiba Corp. Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 Stick (2GB)
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04f3:0103 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ActiveJet K-2024 Multimedia Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 3538:0901 Power Quotient International Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 14cd:8601 Super Top 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:2968 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04f3:0235 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "\n##### PCMCIA card info ##################\n\n"

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ if [ -x /sbin/pccardctl ]; then
> 
>     pccardctl info
> 
> else
> 
>     echo "'pccardctl' is not installed (package \"pcmciautils\")."
> 
> fi
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "\n##### rfkill ############################\n\n"

##### rfkill ############################

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ rfkill list all
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "\n##### lsmod #############################\n\n"

##### lsmod #############################

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ LSMOD=$(lsmod | egrep "(^|[[:punct:] ])($MODMATCHES|$LSMODMATCH 
ES)[^[:punct:] ]*([[:punct:] ]|$)")
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ echo "$LSMOD"
snd_soc_sst_byt_rt5640_mach    12854  0 
acer_wmi               32522  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 acer_wmi
snd_soc_rt5640         93042  0 
snd_soc_rl6231         13037  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_soc_core          200204  2 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_sst_byt_rt5640_mach
snd_pcm               104112  3 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
wmi                    19193  1 acer_wmi
video                  20128  2 i915,acer_wmi
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "\n##### interfaces ########################\n\n"

##### interfaces ########################

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sed '/^#/d;s/^wpa-psk [[:graph:]]\+/wpa-psk <WPA key removed>/' 
 /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "\n##### ifconfig ##########################\n\n"

##### ifconfig ##########################

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ifconfig -a | sed '/^lo /,/^$/d'
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "\n##### iwconfig ##########################\n\n"

##### iwconfig ##########################

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "\n##### route #############################\n\n"

##### route #############################

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "\n##### resolv.conf #######################\n\n"

##### resolv.conf #######################

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ grep -v '^#' /etc/resolv.conf
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "\n##### network managers ##################\n\n"

##### network managers ##################

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "Installed:\n\n"
Installed:

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ for NETMGRNR in "${!NETMGRPATHS[@]}"; do
> 
>     if [ -f "${NETMGRPATHS[$NETMGRNR]}" ]; then
> 
> NETMGRINST+=("${NETMGRNAMES[$NETMGRNR]}")
> 
>     fi
> 
> done
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "\t%s\n" "${NETMGRINST[@]:-None found.}"
    NetworkManager
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ NETMGRMATCHES=${NETMGRPATHS[@]/#*\//|}
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ NETMGRMATCHES=${NETMGRMATCHES// |/|}
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ NETMGRMATCHES="(${NETMGRMATCHES#|})"
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "\nRunning:\n\n"

Running:

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ps -ef | egrep "( |/)$NETMGRMATCHES($| )" || printf "\tNone fou 
nd.\n"
root      1684     1  0 05:39 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "\n##### NetworkManager info ###############\n\n"

##### NetworkManager info ###############

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ if [ -x /usr/bin/nm-tool ]; then
> 
>     nm-tool
> 
> elif [ -x /usr/bin/nmcli ]; then
> 
>     nmcli -f all device show | sed '/^GENERAL.DEVICE:[ ]\+lo$/,/^$/d; /^AP\[[0 
-9]\+\]\./d'
> 
>     echo
> 
>     nmcli -f SSID,BSSID,MODE,CHAN,FREQ,RATE,SIGNAL,BARS,SECURITY,ACTIVE,IN-USE 
 device wifi list
> 
> else
> 
>     echo "NetworkManager is not installed (package \"network-manager\")."
> 
> fi

NetworkManager Tool

State: disconnected

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "\n##### NetworkManager.state ##############\n\n"

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cat -s /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "\n##### NetworkManager.conf ###############\n\n"

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ grep -v '^#' /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ if [ -f /etc/NetworkManager/nm-system-settings.conf ]; then
> 
>     printf "\nnm-system-settings.conf (used up to Ubuntu 10.04):\n\n"
> 
>     grep -v '^#' /etc/NetworkManager/nm-system-settings.conf
> 
> fi
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "\n##### NetworkManager profiles ###########\n\n"

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ if [ -d /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections ]; then
> 
>     if [ -n "$SUDO" ]; then
> 
> trap "" 2 3
> 
> NMPROFILES=$(find /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections -maxdepth 1 -type f - 
exec $SUDO${GKSUDO+ -D grep --}${KDESUDO+ -d --comment "<b>grep</b>$KDESUDOCMT"  
--} grep -vH '^$' {} +) && SUDOSUCCESS="yes" || SUDOSUCCESS="no"
> 
> trap 2 3
> 
> if [ "$SUDOSUCCESS" = "yes" ]; then
> 
>     ORIGIFS="$IFS"
> 
>     IFS=$'\n'
> 
>     for NMWLPRFFILE in $(sed -n 's/^\(.\+\):type=\(802-11-wireless\|wifi\).*$/ 
\1/p' <<< "$NMPROFILES"); do
> 
> 
Display all 2362 possibilities? (y or n)
> MWLPRFFLPERMS=$(stat -c "%a %U" "$NMWLPRFFILE")
> 
> 
Display all 2362 possibilities? (y or n)
> MWLPROFILE=($(sed -n "s;^$NMWLPRFFILE:\($NMPROFMATCHES.*\)$;\1 |;p" <<< "$NMPR 
OFILES"))
> 
> 
Display all 2362 possibilities? (y or n)
> MWLPROFSOUT+="[[$NMWLPRFFILE]] ($NMWLPRFFLPERMS)"$'\n'"${NMWLPROFILE[@]}"$'\n\ 
n'
> 
>     done
> 
>     IFS="$ORIGIFS"
> 
>     sed 's# | \[#\n\[#g;s#\] |#\]#g;s/ |$//' <<< "$NMWLPROFSOUT" | sed '/^\[[^ 
]]*\]$/d'
> 
> else
> 
>     printf "\nAcquisition of admin privileges failed.\n"
> 
> fi
> 
>     else
> 
> echo "No way to acquire admin privileges found."
> 
>     fi
> 
> else
> 
>     echo "No NetworkManager profiles found."
> 
> fi

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "\n##### iw reg get ########################\n\n"

##### iw reg get ########################

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ if [ -x /sbin/iw ]; then
> 
>     if IWREGGET=$(iw reg get 2>&1) && [ -f /etc/timezone ]; then
> 
> REGION=$(cat /etc/timezone)
> 
> printf "Region: %s (based on set time zone)\n\n" "$REGION"
> 
>     fi
> 
>     echo "$IWREGGET"
> 
> else
> 
>     echo "'iw' is not installed (package \"iw\")."
> 
> fi
Region: Etc/UTC (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "\n##### iwlist channels ###################\n\n"

##### iwlist channels ###################

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ if [ -x /sbin/iwlist ]; then
> 
>     iwlist chan
> 
> else
> 
>     echo "'iwlist' is not installed (package \"wireless-tools\")."
> 
> fi
lo        no frequency information.

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "\n##### iwlist scan #######################\n\n"

##### iwlist scan #######################

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ if [ -x /sbin/iwlist ]; then
> 
>     if [ -n "$SUDO" ]; then
> 
> trap "" 2 3
> 
> IWLISTSCAN=$($SUDO${KDESUDO+ -d} iwlist scan) && SUDOSUCCESS="yes" || SUDOSUCC 
ESS="no"
> 
> trap 2 3
> 
> if [ "$SUDOSUCCESS" = "yes" ]; then
> 
>     if [[ $IWLISTSCAN = *Frequency:* ]]; then
> 
> 
Display all 2362 possibilities? (y or n)
> tf "Channel occupancy:\n\n"
> 
> 
Display all 2362 possibilities? (y or n)
:
!
./
[
[[
]]
{
}
2to3
2to3-2.7
2to3-3.4
a2p
aa-exec
aa-status
accept
accessdb
aconnect
acpi_available
acpid
acpi_listen
activity-log-manager
add-apt-repository
addgroup
--More--
[K
addpart
addr2line
add-shell
adduser
agetty
alert
alias
__all_modules
_allowed_groups
_allowed_users
alsa
alsactl
alsaloop
alsamixer
alsaucm
amidi
amixer
amuFormat.sh
anacron
anacron.distrib
apg
apgbfm
aplay
--More--
[K
> uency:' <<< "$IWLISTSCAN" | sort | uniq -c | sed 's/^[ ]\+\([ ][0-9]\+\)[ ]\+/ 
     \1   APs on   /'
> 
> 
.bash_logout       Documents/         Music/             Videos/
.bashrc            Downloads/         Pictures/          wireless-info.txt
.cache/            .gconf/            .profile           .Xauthority
.config/           .ICEauthority      Public/            .xsession-errors
Desktop/           .local/            Templates/         
> echo
> 
>     fi
> 
>     grep -v '^[ ]*IE: Unknown:' <<< "$IWLISTSCAN"
> 
> else
> 
>     printf "\nAcquisition of admin privileges failed.\n"
> 
> fi
> 
>     else
> 
> echo "No way to acquire admin privileges found."
> 
>     fi
> 
> else
> 
>     echo "'iwlist' is not installed (package \"wireless-tools\")."
> 
> fi
> 
> 
> 
> printf "\n##### module infos ######################\n\n"
> 
> MODULES=$(egrep -o "^$MODMATCHES[^ ]*" <<< "$LSMOD")
> 
> for MODULE in $MODULES; do
> 
>     MODINFO=$(modinfo $MODULE | egrep -v "^$MODINFOEXCL:")
> 
>     printf "[%s]\n%s\n\n" "$MODULE" "$MODINFO"
> 
> done
> 
> 
> 
> printf "\n##### module parameters #################\n\n"
> 
> for MODULE in $MODULES; do
> 
>     if [ -d /sys/module/$MODULE/parameters ]; then
> 
> MODPARAMS=$(grep -H '^[[:graph:]]' /sys/module/$MODULE/parameters/* | sed 's#^ 
.*/##;s/:/: /')
> 
> printf "[%s]\n%s\n\n" "$MODULE" "$MODPARAMS"
> 
>     fi
> 
> done
> 
> 
> 
> printf "\n##### /etc/modules ######################\n\n"
> 
> grep -v '^#' /etc/modules
> 
> 
> 
> printf "\n##### modprobe options ##################\n\n"
> 
> for MODPROBEFILE in $(find /etc/modprobe.{conf,d} -name "*.conf" -regextype po 
six-egrep -not -regex ".*$MODPROBEXCL.*" 2> /dev/null | sort); do
> 
>     MODPROBEOPTS=$(egrep -v '^(#|$)' $MODPROBEFILE)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$     if [ -n "$MODPROBEOPTS" ]; then
> 
> printf "[%s]\n%s\n\n" "$MODPROBEFILE" "$MODPROBEOPTS"
> 
>     fi
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ done
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "\n##### rc.local ##########################\n\n"

##### rc.local ##########################

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ grep -v '^#' /etc/rc.local

exit 0
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "\n##### pm-utils ##########################\n\n"

##### pm-utils ##########################

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ for PMUTILSFILE in $(find /etc/pm/*.d \( -type f -o -type l \)  
-regextype posix-egrep -not -regex "$PMUTILSEXCL" | sort); do
> 
>     PMUTFLCONT=$(egrep -v '^(#|$)' $PMUTILSFILE)
> 
>     if [ -n "$PMUTFLCONT" ]; then
> 
> PMUTFLPERMS=$(stat -c "%a %U" $PMUTILSFILE)
> 
> printf "[%s] (%s)\n%s\n\n" "$PMUTILSFILE" "$PMUTFLPERMS" "$PMUTFLCONT"
> 
>     fi
> 
> done
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "\n##### udev rules ########################\n\n"

##### udev rules ########################

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ for UDEVRLFILE in /etc/udev/rules.d/*net*.rules; do
> 
>     UDEVRULES=$(grep -B1 '^[^#]' $UDEVRLFILE | egrep -v '^(--)?$')
> 
>     if [ -n "$UDEVRULES" ]; then
> 
> printf "[%s]\n%s\n\n" "$UDEVRLFILE" "$UDEVRULES"
> 
>     fi
> 
> done
grep: /etc/udev/rules.d/*net*.rules: No such file or directory
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "\n##### dmesg #############################\n\n"

##### dmesg #############################

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dmesg | tail -n 100 | egrep "[[:punct:] ]($MODMATCHES|$DMESGMAT 
CHES)[^[:punct:] ]*[[:punct:] ]" | egrep -v "$DMESGEXCL" | uniq -cf 2 | sed 's/^ 
[ ]\+1[ ]\+//;s/^[ ]\+\([0-9]\+\)[ ]\+\(.\+\)$/\2 (repeated \1 times)/'
[  111.343647] byt-rt5640 byt-rt5640: ASoC: CPU DAI baytrail-pcm-audio not registered
[  111.343679] platform byt-rt5640: Driver byt-rt5640 requests probe deferral
[  111.352333] sst-acpi 80860F28:00: Cannot load firmware intel/fw_sst_0f28.bin-i2s_master
[  111.378651] byt-rt5640 byt-rt5640: ASoC: CPU DAI baytrail-pcm-audio not registered
[  111.378684] platform byt-rt5640: Driver byt-rt5640 requests probe deferral
[  111.423286] byt-rt5640 byt-rt5640: ASoC: CPU DAI baytrail-pcm-audio not registered
[  111.423315] platform byt-rt5640: Driver byt-rt5640 requests probe deferral
[  111.424735] byt-rt5640 byt-rt5640: ASoC: CPU DAI baytrail-pcm-audio not registered
[  111.424764] platform byt-rt5640: Driver byt-rt5640 requests probe deferral
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ printf "\n########## wireless info END ############\n\n"

########## wireless info END ############

]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
]0;ubuntu@ubuntu: ~ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ exec 2>&4 4>&-
```

Comment: It just so happened that I bought the exact same laptop and have been busy the last couple of days to get Ubuntu working here. After a while I managed to make Ubuntu boot by using a 32-bit grub file I compiled. Just out of curiosity, did you need to do this too? On the topic of wifi, I think I found something that might help us (It has helped multiple people), but I haven't tried it yet as I need to backup Windows. Thing is, the link is on another PC;  I will put the link here once I'm able too. I'm also searching for a keyboard solution. (Posted this in order to easily find your post again.)

Comment: As a side note, I read our wifi card used to work, but it's driver hasn't been included or maybe even forgotten (seems more likely).

Comment: If everything is correct, I will receive the things I need to create a backup of Windows later today and after that is done, I can go ahead with installing Ubuntu on my Acer Switch 10. At that point I will begin to try to compile and install the drivers I found on Github (WiFi and Bluetooth created by a, as it seems, reliable coder). If that is done and if I'm successful, I will post the way to do it in here. I haven't been able to find a solution to the keyboard yet, it might be that all it takes is an update.

Comment: 1/2: I've been trying to get Ubuntu 15.04 (since it should have newer software and a better chance of getting everything to work) to install correctly. It's taken this long thanks to some stupidity on my part, but I've learned to read tutorials carefully now :D. I have managed to get 15.04 installed and to get the WiFi to work. Bluetooth and the physical keyboard do not work yet, but the fix for the Bluetooth is created by the same person who created the WiFi fix. For now, the onscreen keyboard works pretty well once it is properly installed.

Comment: 2/2: When run from a live usb it was a bit tricky to use, but you don't need it very much. I'm working on the physical keyboard now. Once I have got everything working correctly I will post a How To and reinstall it myself to make sure I've got it right and to it set up exactly as I want it too. I will keep you up to date. It is a tricky machine, thanks to Acer for shipping a 64-bit machine with 32-bit UEFI BIOS!